# How to construct a locator to identify this element?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

What should be the XPath/CSS for this HTML?? To do MovetoElement, I need to inspect this element, I tried using `//a[@class='product-name']` but multiple nodes get selected.

```
<a class="product-name" itemprop="url" title="Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts" href="http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_product=1&controller=product"> Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts </a>
```

Comment: <a class="product-name" itemprop="url" title="Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts" href="http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_product=1&controller=product"> Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts </a>

Answer (score 2):

There are two main sections of the site, POPULAR and BEST SELLERS. Each have matching elements for the locator you are using. POPULAR is under a `UL` with an ID of `homefeatured`. BEST SELLERS are under a `UL` with an ID of `blockbestsellers`.

Another issue is that your locator is finding both an `A` tag that surrounds the product image and another one that is for the product name. You can use either because the `href` for both is the same but you can specify each, if you want. The product image link is tagged with the class `product_img_link`. The product name is tagged with the class `product-name`.

Putting this all together...

POPULAR > product name

```
#homefeatured a.product-name[title='Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts']
```

POPULAR > product image

```
#homefeatured a.product_img_link[title='Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts']
```

BEST SELLERS > product name

```
#blockbestsellers a.product-name[title='Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts']
```

BEST SELLERS > product image

```
#blockbestsellers a.product_img_link[title='Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts']
```

NOTE: The elements on the POPULAR page are only visible when that tab is selected. The elements on the BEST SELLERS tab will still exist but not be visible and will throw if you try to interact with them.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
//a[@title='Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts']
```

Comment: i am getting 4 matching nodes

Comment: Then you need to share more HTML code, So We can know parent node. And Can check how it has 4 similar element.